# Querying results directly to a DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

When i try to Querying results directly from spring data to a DTO class i get this error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: owner_name of: test.dao.bean.Car [SELECT new test.dto.bean.CarOwners(c.owner_name, c.owner_nid, c.owner_phone, c.driver_name, c.driver_nid, c.driver_phone) FROM test.dao.bean.Car c]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 76 common frames omitted

this is my query:

```
@Query("SELECT new test.dto.bean.CarOwners(c.owner_name, c.owner_nid, c.owner_phone, c.driver_name, c.driver_nid, c.driver_phone) FROM car c")
public List<CarOwners> findAllCarOwners();
```

and this is the DTO class:

```
test.dto.bean;

public class CarOwners{

private String owner_name;
private Long owner_nid;
private Integer owner_phone;
private String driver_name;
private Long driver_nid;
private Integer driver_phone;

 public CarOwners(String owner_name, Long owner_nid, Integer owner_phone, String driver_name, Long driver_nid, Integer driver_phone) {
        this.owner_name = owner_name;
        this.owner_nid = owner_nid;
        this.owner_phone = owner_phone;
        this.driver_name = driver_name;
        this.driver_nid = driver_nid;
        this.driver_phone = driver_phone;

    }

public String getOwner_name() {
    return owner_name;
}


public void setOwner_name(String owner_name) {
    this.owner_name = owner_name;
}


public Long getOwner_nid() {
    return owner_nid;
}


public void setOwner_nid(Long owner_nid) {
    this.owner_nid = owner_nid;
}


public Integer getOwner_phone() {
    return owner_phone;
}


public void setOwner_phone(Integer owner_phone) {
    this.owner_phone = owner_phone;
}


public String getDriver_name() {
    return driver_name;
}


public void setDriver_name(String driver_name) {
    this.driver_name = driver_name;
}


public Long getDriver_nid() {
    return driver_nid;
}


public void setDriver_nid(Long driver_nid) {
    this.driver_nid = driver_nid;
}


public Integer getDriver_phone() {
    return driver_phone;
}


public void setDriver_phone(Integer driver_phone) {
    this.driver_phone = driver_phone;
}
}
```

Any Help please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: owner_name
>   of: test.dao.bean.Car

Apparently , the fields in the select clause should refer to the **Java property name** of the mapped entity (`Car`) rather than the property name in DTO.

So suppose the Car is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="car")
public class Car{


    @Column(name="owner_name")
    private String ownerName;

}
```

Then you should write :

```
@Query("SELECT new test.dto.bean.CarOwners(c.ownerName) FROM car c")
```

Actually , the names of the DTO field have nothing to do with how to write the `@Query` string. It just matches the order between the DTO constructor parameter and the fields in the `SELECT NEW` clause. You can use whatever DTO name as long as their orders and data type are matched.